# Session was invalidated on firefox private window

Tags: java, session, firefox, gwt, web-applications

I am testing a web application on the test environment, when I try to open it from a private window on firefox, a blank page is returned and the log says :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session was invalidated
16/02/02 14:45:17   at com.evermind.server.http.EvermindHttpSession.getId(EvermindHttpSession.java:467)
16/02/02 14:45:17   at cm.listener.SessionListener.sessionCreated(SessionListener.java:14)
16/02/02 14:45:17   at com.evermind.server.http.HttpApplication.createSession(HttpApplication.java:1971)
16/02/02 14:45:17   at com.evermind.server.http.EvermindHttpServletRequest.unprivileged_getSession(EvermindHttpServletRequest.java:2772)
16/02/02 14:45:17   at com.evermind.server.http.EvermindHttpServletRequest.getSession(EvermindHttpServletRequest.java:2661)
16/02/02 14:45:17   at com.evermind.server.http.EvermindHttpServletRequest.getSession(EvermindHttpServletRequest.java:2655)
16/02/02 14:45:17   at utilities.AdsServerFilter.doFilter(AdsServerFilter.java:39)
```

and the line where the exception is thrown is as follows :

```
HttpSession session=httpRequest.getSession();
```

the production version of the application is working fine on private window..

As per my knowledge private window only provides a new private session and also httpRequest.getSession() returns a new session if no existing one was found ... any help?

I am using firefox 26 (and I can't update it so that it continue to support GWT extension)

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with GWT, but is part of how servlet session work if you try to invalidate the session, then in the same request go back to using it.

From the javadoc for HttpSession (available at https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html among other places), the `invalidate()` method breaks nearly any other method called on the session, including itself:

> invalidate
>
> public void invalidate()
>
> Invalidates this session then unbinds any objects bound to it.
>
> Throws:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException - if this method is called on an already invalidated session

You can see from your stack trace that something inside the OC4J server is calling `getId()` on the session as a result of trying to create the session. This method also has the same exception:

> getId
>
> public java.lang.String getId()
>
> Returns a string containing the unique identifier assigned to this session. The identifier is assigned by the servlet container and is implementation dependent.
>
> Returns:
>   a string specifying the identifier assigned to this session
>
> Throws:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException - if this method is called on an invalidated session

The question is now "why is your session already invalidated?" - are you also calling invalidate at some other point in your code inside this same request? Or perhaps is there a bug in OC4J where it fails to create new sessions for private browsers?